# how to join arbitrary view in tableMethod

Tags: view, symfony1, doctrine, left-join

I have a doctrine data model with a table Person, however my Symfony application is only part of a bigger web application, which is build in Joomla. For a module, I need to add a number of fields from a view, which spans 8 tables with the person table. The view is already established for the Joomla part of things.

Short of creating a schema for all the tables involved, is there a way to arbitrarily join  the view in my tableMethod? As another shortcut I am thinking of creating a minimal schema.yml table to just represent the field of the view that I need.

Comment: If you don't need to do a whole lot with the non-Doctrine tables, then greg0ire's suggestion of just writing native SQL queries is probably the simplest solution.

Comment: Thanks, it turns out the minimal schema.yml is actually the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

another solution would be to [use native sql with doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/native-sql)